# Sometimes Linux doesn't boot at all (not even GRUB, no sign of life)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, blank-screen

Now I only have Linux (an Ubuntu flavor) on my laptop, but the same problem appeared some time ago when I still had a dual boot setup (Linux and Windows). What happens is very strange, because it doesn't happen all the time, but lately it happens pretty often anyway (maybe even 50% of the times).

What often happens is something like this:

- I turn on the laptop and the brand logo appears
- The screen might turn black (I'm not sure if the logo is still there lately), and then nothing happens.
- Hitting ESC, F keys, shift, enter, etc. doesn't do anything. I'm not sure if hitting any keys earlier would have worked, because of course when I notice the problem it seems too late. I have entered the firmware setup lately, but I'm not sure if I can always enter it (I would have to try several times to have a good statistics). Once it's stuck with the black screen though, as I said, no key would do anything (so I cannot enter setup).
- The HDD led isn't flashing, the disk is quiet, so it isn't actually doing anything
- I force the laptop to turn off by keeping the power button pressed.
- I turn on the laptop again, and usually (but not always) the second time it works, even though the boot process looks a bit different than usual. Normally, if everything is ok on the first attempt, GRUB would not appear in single boot setups, or GRUB would appear with an 8-second countdown in dual boot if I'm not mistaken. But when I turn on the laptop after a "failure", I now see GRUB even if I have a single boot setup, and when I had the dual boot I would see GRUB with an unexpected extended countdown of 30 seconds. I also see some error lines on the screen but they disappear pretty fast. Everything seems to work ok then though, including unlocking the HDD, which is encrypted with LUKS.

To me, it looks like sometimes the laptop isn't even seeing the HDD. When I see the HDD buzzing and the led flashing, then I know the boot process is going to be ok and I'm going to see the prompt to unlock the encrypted HDD soon after. Otherwise, if I don't see any HDD activity within a few seconds from when I turn on the laptop, then I know nothing is going to happen and the black screen will be there forever.

The output of `smartctl` doesn't seem too bad, especially when compared to past values (some values have been increasing over time, but pretty gradually). Reallocated_Event_Count, Current_Pending_Sector, Offline_Uncorrectable are all 0. Only Raw_Read_Error_Rate is 1. Multi_Zone_Error_Rate is over 2000, but that's been increasing slowly over the years, I don't know why. So I don't think it's a problem related to bad data on the disk.

Has anyone had this problem or heard of it? What could I do to find out more about its cause? Should I be worried of impending hardware failures of any kind?

Comment: It could be the UEFI not working well with grub. Maybe try another bootloader / boot manager and see if it works better.